# How to encoding of Lyx LaTeX output without Lyx adding inputenc declaration to preamble

Tags: lyx, input-encodings

I want to specify encoding that is used by Lyx when it generates LaTeX source for preview or export. That is not a big problem Document->Settings->Language->Encoding->Other->Select encoding from combo box will do just that. But it will also add command `\usepackage[selectedEncoding]{inputenc}` to preamble of generated document.

How do I prevent that? I want all my LaTeX documents to be generated in UTF-8 but I do not want that inputenc declaration in preamble.

Comment: Why this automatic `inputenc` declaration is it a problem?

Comment: @Paul Gaborit Because LaTeX class of the document may also declare `inputenc` therefore there is option clash possible. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88177/option-clash-for-package-inputenc-when-using-lyx-with-latex-class-that-already-u

Comment: A LaTeX class should not impose specific encoding.

Comment: @Paul Gaborit Thank you for this! This is what I needed to hear (hope this is not your subjective opinion). Apparently Lyx also expect LaTeX classes to not to impose specific encodings. Would you mind answering my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88177/option-clash-for-package-inputenc-when-using-lyx-with-latex-class-that-already-u in this manner? It might be accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You more or less answered your own question:

[image]

By selecting *Language Default (no inputenc)*  as encoding, LyX will not add `\usepackage[<encoding>]{inputenc}`  to the preamble.

Comment: Why don't I even have the option to set the encoding?! And how do I fix it if I don't have "Encoding" in my language settings? Do I have an old version or did it change over time?
So many questions : ( There is only "Language" and a dropdown box for that.

Comment: @Garrin I have no idea. To find out which version you have, go to Help --> About LyX. The latest version is 2.0.6, you can download it from http://www.lyx.org/

Comment: I have this setting, but the whole *Encoding* fieldset (in HTML terms) is disabled. How can one enable that?

Comment: @Zelphir No idea why it would be disabled, ask in the LyX users mailing list (http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists#toc2) or post a new question here.